# ALM : How to pass parameters through ALM to Performance Center?

Tags: loadrunner, alm, vugen, hp-performance-center

I have recorder a script in VUGen installed on my machine. The script is uploading files from my system. The file path is parameterized like `"Name=file", "Value={filePath}", "File=Yes"`

{filePath} contains path of a csv file and that csv has many file paths. It will get a different file path for each VUser.

When I try to run this script from ALM (Web) and Performance Center (Web), the script is not able to pick up the file path from machine as it has generated its own virtual machines and running my script on those machines.

How can I parameterize this in ALM, so that {filePath} will pick the file with all the paths and pass it to my script?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In order for LG to see your parameterization file it should be uploaded to ALM with your script or placed manually in the shared location if you have access to LG machines.
To upload the file to ALM, in VuGen go to File->Save Script As dialog and choose ALM Test in left menu. When prompted, choose "All Files Mode" in the "Working Mode" dialog.
Make sure you specify relative path to your parameterization file.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.
In the VUGen, I added my files to the extra files folder and gave the relative path of it in parameterization and it worked just fine.
Here is the reference link : https://community.softwaregrp.com/t5/Performance-Center-Practitioners/Uploading-test-files-using-Performance-Center/td-p/579874

Thanks a lot for your answer Albert for your response. That solves another of my doubts of "Running Mode" and "All File Mode".